# How to connect to the internet reliably

Tags: network-manager, internet, settings, dsl

I have a DSL internet connection. For a long time the internet functioned fine in Ubuntu using the default Network Manager. Recently however, my ISP was bought by another ISP, and the service name had to be changed in the DSL settings. In Windows, it connects without any issue whatsoever. But in Ubuntu, the first time I connect I get a "Apache: Not Found" page, the next time, I get to the previous ISP's login page, it continues like this for some time until I get it working. I have to try connecting it again and again.

When I asked the customer service, they said that because of the takeover, they have switched servers. But they said, it should work properly in Windows, and they were clueless about Ubuntu. Is there anything I can do to solve this issue?

Comment: To answer this we need to know more. How is your box connected, DSL modem only, or router? What **exactly** did change for your ISP's settings? There is no sensible reason why network manager should not connect if settings are correct.

Comment: Yeah, the DSL is just a cable that comes into my house, no routers under my control. The only thing that changed (apparently) is the service name. Just changing this make the internet work fine in Windows. It seems every time I reconnect, it connects to a different server, until I reach the correct one in the end...

Comment: Well, I guess I have to try the forums. Anyways, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

There's a service name field in the settings on the main page for DSL connections. You should file in the service name there, as well as the usual username and password information.

If you find you're having issues with the service name entered, try to set the connection without a service name. This seems to work better in some cases.